# Getting "unrecognized selector error" in the first function I've ever built

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting to learn iOS and following the Stanford course, there we build a card flip function.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71pyOB4TPRE&list=PLPA-ayBrweUzGFmkT_W65z64MoGnKRZMq

In the 45th minute when I try to run my app I get "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

The project is single page project and I'm running with XCode 8.2.1 (not sure about the swift version) due to OS limitation.

When I debug I see that the error comes from a part of the code I did not write:
on `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` (this is the debugger breakpoint).

The code I wrote is identical to the one on the video.

***EDIT***

This is the flipCard method plus the touchCard method that calls it(basically the entire code)

```
 @IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {

        flipCard(withEmoji: "", on: sender)
    }
    func flipCard (withEmoji emoji: String, on button: UIButton){

        if button.currentTitle == emoji {
            button.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
```

When attaching the button to the code I used the following:
Connection: Action
Type: UIButton
Name:touchCard
Event: TouchUpInside
Arguments: sender

This is the error msg received:

> 2019-05-22 23:21:09.522 Concetration2[2100:5096626]
>   -[Concetration2.ViewController flipCard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9933e01fc0 (lldb)

Thanks

Comment: Show full error message. It's a known error.

Comment: 2019-05-22 22:31:51.888 Concetration2[2045:5063104] -[Concetration2.ViewController flipCard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff08be07bc0
(lldb)

Comment: We are not going to watch the video, add any relevant code as text to your question.

Comment: Edit your question with that log. Also, show us the code of `flipCard:`. Is it a button called event action? How is it declared? Did you use a addAction/Selector/Target? Did you connect it only through Storyboard?

Comment: Fix your storyboard. It seems there is a connection to method `flipCard(_:)` (with one argument!) which no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your connection between your button and it's function is correct throw the below image: 
make sure every red arrow is correct

[image]